# perform lm with multiple outcomes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
> df <- dput(df2)
structure(list(Economy = c("FRANCE", "FRANCE", "SPAIN", "SPAIN", 
"GREECE", "GREECE", "ITALY", "ITALY", "PORTUGAL", "PORTUGAL"), 
    ConditionA = c(9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 12, 13), ConditionB = c(16, 
    16, 18, 21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 36, 36), ConditionC = c(27, 29, 
    31, 34, 41, 48, 52, 56, 56, 56), ConditionD = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame


> df2
    Economy ConditionA ConditionB ConditionC ConditionD
1    FRANCE          9         16         27         NA
2    FRANCE         12         16         29         NA
3     SPAIN         12         18         31         NA
4     SPAIN         12         21         34         NA
5    GREECE         12         27         41         NA
6    GREECE         12         27         48         NA
7     ITALY         13         30         52         NA
8     ITALY         13         36         56         NA
9  PORTUGAL         12         36         56         NA
10 PORTUGAL         13         36         56         NA
```

I would like to run a linear regression of each condition for each country.

```
    df %>% 
      dplyr::select(-Economy) %>%  # exclude outcome, leave only predictors 
      map(~lm(.x ~ Economy , data =df, na.action = "na.omit"))  %>%
      map(summary)
     Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I have 188 conditions in the original dataframe. What´s wrong ?

Comment: `ConditionD` is all NA, and the code runs fine if I de-select that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides fixing ConditionD, you can regress all of them at one go:

```
M = df2[,grep("Condition",colnames(df2))]
M = as.matrix(M[,colSums(!is.na(M))>0])

fit = lm(M ~ Economy,data=df2)

lapply(summary(fit),coefficients)

$`Response ConditionA`
                Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         10.5  0.7071068 14.84924 2.505578e-05
EconomyGREECE        1.5  1.0000000  1.50000 1.939037e-01
EconomyITALY         2.5  1.0000000  2.50000 5.449010e-02
EconomyPORTUGAL      2.0  1.0000000  2.00000 1.019395e-01
EconomySPAIN         1.5  1.0000000  1.50000 1.939037e-01

$`Response ConditionB`
                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         16.0    1.50000 10.666667 0.0001253456
EconomyGREECE       11.0    2.12132  5.185450 0.0035093242
EconomyITALY        17.0    2.12132  8.013877 0.0004889171
EconomyPORTUGAL     20.0    2.12132  9.428090 0.0002265750
EconomySPAIN         3.5    2.12132  1.649916 0.1598731108

$`Response ConditionC`
                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         28.0   1.974842 14.178351 3.142696e-05
EconomyGREECE       16.5   2.792848  5.907948 1.978175e-03
EconomyITALY        26.0   2.792848  9.309493 2.406736e-04
EconomyPORTUGAL     28.0   2.792848 10.025608 1.688635e-04
EconomySPAIN         4.5   2.792848  1.611258 1.680400e-01
```

I think now `tidy` in `broom` works with this mlm:

```
library(broom)
tidy(fit)
# A tibble: 15 x 6
   response   term            estimate std.error statistic   p.value
   <chr>      <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 ConditionA (Intercept)        10.5      0.707     14.8  0.0000251
 2 ConditionA EconomyGREECE       1.5      1.         1.5  0.194    
 3 ConditionA EconomyITALY        2.5      1.         2.50 0.0545   
 4 ConditionA EconomyPORTUGAL     2.       1.         2    0.102    
 5 ConditionA EconomySPAIN        1.5      1.         1.5  0.194    
 6 ConditionB (Intercept)        16.0      1.50      10.7  0.000125 
 7 ConditionB EconomyGREECE      11.       2.12       5.19 0.00351  
 8 ConditionB EconomyITALY       17.       2.12       8.01 0.000489 
 9 ConditionB EconomyPORTUGAL    20.       2.12       9.43 0.000227 
10 ConditionB EconomySPAIN        3.5      2.12       1.65 0.160    
11 ConditionC (Intercept)        28        1.97      14.2  0.0000314
12 ConditionC EconomyGREECE      16.5      2.79       5.91 0.00198  
13 ConditionC EconomyITALY       26.0      2.79       9.31 0.000241 
14 ConditionC EconomyPORTUGAL    28.0      2.79      10.0  0.000169 
15 ConditionC EconomySPAIN        4.50     2.79       1.61 0.168
```

Comment: That looks good, the problem i have with this is that i have NA values in some columns (not in this matrix). In this exemple there was one column with all NA values but for some other columns i still have both NA values and numeric. How to handle this ?

Comment: A few NAs is fine. The issue you have up there is that the whole column is NA. And in situations where one of your countries turn out to be all NAs, then the coefficient is NA

Comment: One column has too many NA´s, so i end up getting only one factor.  can i modify the code to handle such cases ?

Comment: you mean you can only estimate one country? wait lemme try

Comment: tidy(fit) %>% group_by(response) %>% filter(sum(!is.na(estimate))>=4) ; this will take only response with at least 4 non-NAs for estimates.. you can modify this